# when deleting Tree item destructor not being called

Tags: qt, qt5

when i am deleting Treeitem from the the tree model the destructor for the tree item is not being called.

This is my code for deleting the tree item from the model.

```
 void TreeModel::removeItem(TreeItem *node)
  {
    const int row = node->row();
    QModelIndex idx = createIndex(row, 0, node);
    TreeItem* itm = getItem(idx);
    beginRemoveRows(idx.parent(), row, row);
    node->parent()->removeChild(row);
   endRemoveRows();
  }
```

The code for Treeitem RemoveChild.

```
void TreeItem::removeChild(int row)
{  
   childItems.removeAt(row);
}
```

The code for tree item header file.

```
#include <QList>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QVector>
#include "Container.h"

class TreeItem
{
 public:
   explicit TreeItem( Container *data , TreeItem *parent = 0 );
   ~TreeItem();
   TreeItem *parent();
   void appendChild(TreeItem *child);

   TreeItem *child(int iNumber);
   int childCount() const;
   int childNumber() const;
   Container data() const ;
   Container* GetContainer();
   bool setData(Container* data , QVariant value);
   void setContainer( Container* data);
   bool insertChildren(int position, int count );
   bool removeChildren( int position  , int count );
   void removeChild(int row);
   void removeChild(TreeItem* itm);
  std::string getChildName(int row);
  std::string getName();
  int row() const;
  void insertChild(int pos, TreeItem *child);

private:
  QList<TreeItem*> childItems;
  Container* itemData;
  TreeItem* parentItem;
 };
```

The code for the tree item Cpp file.
/////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
TreeItem::TreeItem( Container *data, TreeItem *parent )
 {
   parentItem = parent;
   itemData = new Container;
   *itemData = *data;   
  }

     TreeItem::~TreeItem()
      { 
      qDebug() << itemData->GetName().c_str();
      if (itemData != nullptr)
      {
       delete itemData;
       qDebug() << "deleting Item Data";

      } 
    qDeleteAll(childItems);
  }

 TreeItem *TreeItem::parent()
 {
    return parentItem;
 }

 TreeItem *TreeItem::child(int iNumber)
 {
   return childItems.value(iNumber);
  }

int TreeItem::childCount() const 
{
    return childItems.count();
}

int TreeItem::childNumber() const
{
    if (parentItem)
       return parentItem->childItems.indexOf(const_cast<TreeItem*> (this));

    return 0;
}

 Container TreeItem::data() const
 {
    return *itemData;
 }

 bool TreeItem::setData( Container* data , QVariant value )
 {
    //*itemData = *data;  // Do Not !!!! uncomment this as it will set the 
 value of default container constructor.
    itemData->SetName(value.toString().toStdString() );
    return true;
}

 bool TreeItem::insertChildren(int position, int count)
 {
     if (position < 0 || position > childItems.count())
        return false;

   Container cont;
   TreeItem *item = new TreeItem(&cont, this);
   childItems.insert(position, item);

   return true;
}

 bool TreeItem::removeChildren(int position, int count)
 {
    if (position < 0 || position > childItems.count())
       return false;

     for (int row = 0; row < count; ++row)
     {
       delete childItems.takeAt(position);
     }

     return true;
  }

 void TreeItem::setContainer( Container* cont)
 {
     *itemData = *cont; 
 }

  void TreeItem::appendChild(TreeItem *node)
 {
   childItems.append( node );
  }

 int TreeItem::row() const
  {

   if (parentItem)
     return parentItem->childItems.indexOf( const_cast<TreeItem*>(this) );

    return 0;
   }

 void TreeItem::removeChild(int row)
  {  
    childItems.removeAt(row);
  } 

 void TreeItem::insertChild(int pos, TreeItem *child)
 {
    childItems.insert(pos, child);
     child->parentItem = this;
 }

 void TreeItem::removeChild(TreeItem* itm)
 {
   childItems.removeOne(itm);
 }

 std::string TreeItem::getChildName(int row)
 {
   return childItems.value(row)->getName();
 }

std::string TreeItem::getName()
 {
    return itemData->GetName();
 }

 Container* TreeItem::GetContainer()
  {
     return itemData;
   }
```

The Header file for the TreeModel Class///////////////////////////////////

```
  #pragma once
 #include <QAbstractItemModel>
 #include <QString>
 #include <QMimedata.h>
 #include <Qdatastream.h>
 class TreeItem;
 class Container;
 class TreeModel : public QAbstractItemModel
  {
Q_OBJECT

    public:

TreeModel(const QString &header, Container *data, QObject *parent = 0);
~TreeModel();

QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole) override;
bool setHeaderData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
    const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole)  override;

QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;

bool insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent);
//  bool removeRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) override;
Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const override;

int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;


Container* GetContainer(const QModelIndex &index);
void SetContainer(const QModelIndex &index, Container* cont);

////////////////////// Drag And Drop Actions ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const override;
Qt::DropActions supportedDragActions() const override;
QStringList mimeTypes() const override;
QMimeData *mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const override;
bool dropMimeData(const QMimeData* data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent);
void setupModelData(const QStringList &lines, TreeItem *parent);
void removeItem(TreeItem *item);
bool FindChild(std::string stdstrChildName);
TreeItem *getItem(const QModelIndex &index) const;
TreeItem *getRoot();


  private:
//void setupModelData(const Container &cont, TreeItem *parent);
TreeItem *rootItem;

 };
```

The Cpp file for the TreeModel

```
 #include "TreeModel.h"
 #include "TreeItem.h"
 #include <qcoreapplication.h>
 #include <qdebug.h>
 #include "Container.h"


 TreeItem *TreeModel::getItem(const QModelIndex &index) const
 {
if (index.isValid()) {
    TreeItem *item = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());
    if (item)
        return item;
}

return rootItem;
}

 TreeModel::TreeModel(const QString &header,  Container *data, QObject 
 *parent) : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
 {

 qDebug() << "First level done";
 rootItem = new TreeItem( data);    
 }

  TreeModel::~TreeModel()
  {
delete rootItem;
  }

 QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
  {
if (!index.isValid())
    return QVariant();

if (role != Qt::DisplayRole && role != Qt::EditRole)
    return QVariant();

TreeItem *item = getItem(index);
return QString::fromStdString(item->data().GetName());

//return QVariant::fromValue(item->data());
  }

  QVariant TreeModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
int role) const
  {
if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    return QVariant::fromValue(rootItem->data());

return QVariant();
   }

  bool TreeModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &val, int 
 role)
 {
if (role != Qt::EditRole)
    return false;

Container c = val.value<Container>();
TreeItem *item = getItem(index);
bool result = true;
item->setData(&c, val);

if (result)
    emit dataChanged(index, index, { role });


return result;
 }

 QModelIndex TreeModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) 
 const
 {
if (parent.isValid() && parent.column() != 0)
    return QModelIndex();

TreeItem *parentItem = getItem(parent);
TreeItem *childItem = parentItem->child(row);

if (childItem)
    return createIndex(row, column, childItem);
else
    return QModelIndex();
 }

 QModelIndex TreeModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
 {
if (!index.isValid())
    return QModelIndex();

TreeItem *childItem = getItem(index);
TreeItem *parentItem = childItem->parent();

if (parentItem == rootItem)
    return QModelIndex();

return createIndex(parentItem->row(), 0, parentItem);
 }

 bool TreeModel::setHeaderData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, const QVariant &val, int role)
 {
if (role != Qt::EditRole || orientation != Qt::Horizontal)
    return false;

Container c = val.value<Container>();
bool result = rootItem->setData(&c, val);

if (result)
    emit headerDataChanged(orientation, section, section);

return result;
 }

 bool TreeModel::insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent)
 {
TreeItem *parentItem = getItem(parent);
bool success;

beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1);
success = parentItem->insertChildren(position, rows);
endInsertRows();
return success;
}


 Qt::ItemFlags TreeModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
 {
if (!index.isValid())
    return Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled;

return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
 }

 int TreeModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
if (parent.column() > 0)
    return 1;

TreeItem *parentItem = getItem(parent);

//qDebug() << "the child count = " << parentItem->childCount() << parentItem->data().GetName().c_str();
return parentItem->childCount();
 }

int TreeModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex & /* parent */) const
{ 
return 1;
}

Container* TreeModel::GetContainer(const QModelIndex &index)
{
TreeItem *item = getItem(index);
return item->GetContainer();
 }

 void  TreeModel::SetContainer(const QModelIndex &index,  Container* Cont)
 {
TreeItem *item = getItem(index);
item->setContainer(Cont);   
 }

 static const char s_treeNodeMimeType[] = "application/x-treenode";

 QStringList TreeModel::mimeTypes() const
 {
return QStringList() << s_treeNodeMimeType;
 }

 QMimeData *TreeModel::mimeData(const QModelIndexList  &indexes) const
 {
QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
QByteArray data; //a kind of RAW format for datas

//QDataStream is independant on the OS or proc architecture
//serialization of C++'s basic data types, like char, short, int, char *, etc.
//Serialization of more complex data is accomplished
//by breaking up the data into primitive units.
QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QList<TreeItem *> nodes;

//
foreach(const QModelIndex &index, indexes) {
    TreeItem *node = getItem(index);
    if (!nodes.contains(node))
        nodes << node;
}
stream << QCoreApplication::applicationPid();
stream << nodes.count();
foreach(TreeItem *node, nodes) {
    stream << reinterpret_cast<qlonglong>(node);
}
mimeData->setData(s_treeNodeMimeType, data);
return mimeData;
 }

 bool TreeModel::dropMimeData(const QMimeData *mimeData, Qt::DropAction 
 action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)
 {
//Q_ASSERT(action == Qt::MoveAction);
//Q_UNUSED(column);
//test if the data type is the good one
if (!mimeData->hasFormat(s_treeNodeMimeType)) {
    return false;
}
QByteArray data = mimeData->data(s_treeNodeMimeType);
QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
qint64 senderPid;
stream >> senderPid;
if (senderPid != QCoreApplication::applicationPid()) {
    // Let's not cast pointers that come from another process...
    return false;
}
TreeItem *parentNode = getItem(parent);
//  Q_ASSERT(parentNode);
int count;
stream >> count;

if (row == -1) {
    // valid index means: drop onto item. I chose that this should insert
    // a child item, because this is the only way to create the first child 
  of an item...
    // This explains why Qt calls it parent: unless you just support 
    replacing, this
    // is really the future parent of the dropped items.
    if (parent.isValid())
        row = 0;
    else
        // invalid index means: append at bottom, after last toplevel               
        row = rowCount(parent);
}

//qDebug() << "The row" << row << parentNode->data().GetName().c_str() ;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    // Decode data from the QMimeData
    qlonglong nodePtr;
    stream >> nodePtr;
    TreeItem *node = reinterpret_cast<TreeItem *>(nodePtr);

    // Adjust destination row for the case of moving an item
    // within the same parent, to a position further down.
    // Its own removal will reduce the final row number by one.
    if (node->row() < row  && parentNode == node->parent())
        --row;

    // Remove from old position
//  qDebug() << "The remove item " << node->data().GetName().c_str();
    removeItem(node);

    // Insert at new position
    //qDebug() << "Inserting into" << parent << row;
    beginInsertRows(parent, row, row);
    parentNode->insertChild(row, node);
    endInsertRows();
    ++row;
}
return true;
}

 void TreeModel::removeItem(TreeItem *node)
 {
const int row = node->row();
QModelIndex idx = createIndex(row, 0, node);
TreeItem* itm = getItem(idx);
beginRemoveRows(idx.parent(), row, row);
node->parent()->removeChild(row);
endRemoveRows();
  }

 Qt::DropActions TreeModel::supportedDropActions() const
{
return Qt::MoveAction;
}

Qt::DropActions TreeModel::supportedDragActions() const
{
return Qt::MoveAction;
}

 void TreeModel::setupModelData(const QStringList &lines, TreeItem *parent)
 {
QList<TreeItem*> parents;
QList<int> indentations;
parents << parent;
indentations << 0;

int number = 0;

while (number < lines.count()) {
    int position = 0;
    while (position < lines[number].length()) {
        if (lines[number].mid(position, 1) != " ")
            break;
        position++;
    }

    QString lineData = lines[number].mid(position).trimmed();

    if (!lineData.isEmpty()) {
        // Read the column data from the rest of the line.
        QStringList columnStrings = lineData.split("\t", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
        QList<QVariant> columnData;
        for (int column = 0; column < columnStrings.count(); ++column)
            columnData << columnStrings[column];

        if (position > indentations.last()) {
            // The last child of the current parent is now the new parent
            // unless the current parent has no children.

            if (parents.last()->childCount() > 0) {
                parents << parents.last()->child(parents.last()->childCount() - 1);
                indentations << position;
            }
        }
        else {
            while (position < indentations.last() && parents.count() > 0) {
                parents.pop_back();
                indentations.pop_back();
            }
        }
        Container c;
        // Append a new node to the current parent's list of children.
        parents.last()->appendChild(new TreeItem(&c, parents.last()));
    }

    ++number;
}
 }

TreeItem *TreeModel::getRoot()
 {
return rootItem;
 }
```

Comment: What is `TreeItem::removeChilde(int)` method? Or the whole `TreeItem` class? Or `TreeModel` class for that matter? Please edit the question with more code. I mean, I don't even see `delete` there.

Comment: @hyde i have added the code for tree item remove child , if you need to see any more code i would be happy to post it.

Comment: Well, I still don't know what these classes and methods are. It seems you want to know why `removeAt(int)` method does not do delete. We still don't know what that method *is*. Is it inherited from some Qt class? Please link to the docs of the Qt method to make things easy and clear.

Comment: @hyde i have added the complete treeitem and treemodel classes.

Comment: @hyde i am able to remove the item from the tree view but when i remove the item the destructor for the item is not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`childItems.removeOne(itm);` and `childItems.removeAt(row);` just remove `TreeItem *` from your `QList<TreeItem*> childItems;` so memory is not freed.

You should explicitly call `delete`, once they are removed as you did with `delete childItems.takeAt(position);` for example.